# Listview gets recreated and changes the previous views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a ListView in which I inflate 4 different layouts dynamically. In every Item in listview the common things are 3 buttons. Like ,dislike, comment. So when we click on like it shows up with gallery with profile pictures related to like. And same way for dislike and comment. 
The problem arises that when I click on like it will show up proper data but when I scroll down and when that Item is out of view then when i scroll back up to view that Item it changes its view with some other button click.
This happens foe every Item in ListView
Need a urgent help
Code of getView:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mInflater= LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            pos=position;
        if(convertView==null){
            Log.e("--------Inside---------", "convertView==null");
            holder= new Holder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_stream_list, null);
            holder.childView= (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_to_inflate);
            holder.myGallery= (Gallery) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myGallery_stream);
            holder.like= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_stream);
            holder.dislike =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dislike_stream);
            holder.comment = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_stream);
            holder.commentLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_view_to_inflate);
            holder.comment_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_name);
            holder.comment_description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_description);
            holder.comment_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_time);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            Log.e("--------Inside---------", "else Statement");
            holder= (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.myGallery.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        holder.like.setTag(holder);
        holder.dislike.setTag(holder);
        holder.comment.setTag(holder);



        holder.myGallery.setSpacing(5);


        holder.like.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.dislike.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.comment.setOnClickListener(this);


        if((position%4)==0){
            Log.e("--------Inside---------", "position==0");
            followLayoutView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.abc, null);
            holder.news_titile=(TextView) followLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.news_article_titile);
            holder.news_description= (TextView) followLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.news_article_description);
            holder.childView.removeAllViews();
            holder.childView.addView(followLayoutView);

        } if((position%4)==1){
            Log.e("--------Inside---------", "position==1");
            followLayoutView1 = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, null);
            holder.match_event_title= (TextView) followLayoutView1.findViewById(R.id.match_events_stream_titile);
            holder.match_event_time= (TextView) followLayoutView1.findViewById(R.id.following_time);
            holder.match_event_description= (TextView) followLayoutView1.findViewById(R.id.match_events_stream_description);
            holder.childView.removeAllViews();
            holder.childView.addView(followLayoutView1);


        } if((position%4)== 2){
            Log.e("--------Inside---------", "position==2");
            followLayoutView2 = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pqr, null);
            holder.match_event_title= (TextView) followLayoutView2.findViewById(R.id.match_events_stream_titile);
            holder.match_event_time= (TextView) followLayoutView2.findViewById(R.id.following_time);
            holder.match_event_description= (TextView) followLayoutView2.findViewById(R.id.match_events_stream_description);
            holder.childView.removeAllViews();
            holder.childView.addView(followLayoutView2);

        } if((position%4)==3){
            Log.e("--------Inside---------", "position==3");
            followLayoutView3 = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mno, null);
            holder.video_background= (ImageView) followLayoutView3.findViewById(R.id.video_background);
            holder.play = (ImageView) followLayoutView3.findViewById(R.id.video_play);
            holder.childView.removeAllViews();
            holder.childView.addView(followLayoutView3);


        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are not using Holder for your dynamic list.
Use Holder Pattern in order to avoid that issue.
Hope this link helps.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: in that case, it would be easier to diagnose if you could post the adapter part of your code